# Data sync between on Prem MySQL and Azure Data Store

Tags: mysql, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

We have a legacy system which talks to on-premise MySQL database. We are building a new system and its hosted in Azure. The database it uses to store the data is in Azure Storage. Since the legacy application will be functional for some time, we would like to sync the data from MySQL to Azure Table Storage. Is there any tool that can help in the synchronization of the data from MySQL to Azure Table Storage?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Data-in Replication feature for synchronization of data between MYSQL and Azure database.

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-data-in-replication) document for more information.

Hope it helps.